# R reshape converting all the values to 1

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

My original data looks like this

```
data
id1,id2,value
A,1,-1.09
B,1,-1.033
C,1,-1.5
A,2,9.1
B,2,2.006
C,2,-3.95
```

I tried using reshape package in R to reshape it using the command `cast(data, id2 ~ id1)` but this is converting all my values from value column to 1 like this

```
   A       B      C   
1  1       1      1 
2  1       1      1
```

when I actually want it to be like this. Can anyone please help me out.

```
  A       B      C   
1  -1.09   -1.033 -1.5
2  9.1     2.006  -3.95
```

EDIT: IT WORKED FOR ME when I added fun.aggregate = mean at the end of cast function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dcast` in `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
##
data <- read.table(
  text="id1 id2  value
A   1   -1.09
B   1   -1.033
C   1   -1.5
A   2   9.1
B   2   2.006
C   2   -3.95",
  header=TRUE)
##
> dcast(data,id2~id1)
  id2     A      B     C
1   1 -1.09 -1.033 -1.50
2   2  9.10  2.006 -3.95
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My data is actually from a csv file. So I figured out that the 1's are the number of times data in id2 is repeated. I'd like to have the values from value column instead.

Comment: @abn This answer does what you want as well. These days, most people seem to prefer the `reshape2` package as it's more user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the aggregate function towards the end.

```
cast(data, id2 ~ id1,fun.aggregate = mean)
```